# jQuery UI dialog box not aligning correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In jQuery I call a few dialog boxes in sequence to create a wizard. Despite setting the position to `position: ["center", "center"]`, the dialogs align to left center.

The wizard starts by calling `getMoreParams(0).` There are 7 divs in the HTML spanning moreParams[0-7].

Please let me know if more detail is required.
[**See video here.**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WV2D0EEBWYw)

Code is:

```
 function getMoreParams(divNumber) {
        $("#moreParams" + divNumber).addClass("isWizard");
        $("#moreParams" + divNumber).dialog({
            title: "Designing wizard",
            width: "300px",
            resizable: false,
            position: ["center", "center"]
        });
        if (divNumber == 0) {
            $("#moreParams" + divNumber).dialog({
                modal: true,
                position: ["center", "center"],
                buttons: {
                    "Let's get started": function() {
                        getMoreParams(divNumber + 1);
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        if (divNumber == 1) {
            $("#moreParams" + divNumber).dialog({
                modal: true,
                position: ["center", "center"],
                buttons: {
                    "Next": function() {
                        getMoreParams(divNumber + 1);
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        if (divNumber > 1 && divNumber < 6) {
            $("#moreParams" + divNumber).dialog({
                modal: true,
                position: ["center", "center"],
                buttons: {
                    "Next": function() {
                        getMoreParams(divNumber + 1);
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Previous": function() {
                        getMoreParams(divNumber - 1);
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        if (divNumber == 6) {
            $("#moreParams" + divNumber).dialog({
                modal: true,
                position: ["center", "center"],
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        lastStep();
                    },
                    "Previous": function() {
                        getMoreParams(divNumber - 1);
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        } 
}
```

Comment: It works fine here. The divs centers correctly in firefox and chrome. Looking at the video (nice, btw :)) it seems the dialog popped by `lastStep()` is centered correctly. What's different with this dialog, compared to the ones opened by `getMoreParams()`?

Comment: Same here, you must some bug in an other part of your javascript code. In the video, we see the dialog popping in the center and then go to the left corner, so try to find what is the code that produce this effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was isolated to the application it was running in.

I have been unable to reproduce this in other applications.

Closing this question, but feel free to edit, as this is a wiki.